# why wait.Until is not working? Error: element is not attached to the page document

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am having this error: element is not attached to the page document

```
OpenQA.Selenium.StaleElementReferenceException : stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

I am using wait.Until but is not working, sometimes my test is passing and sometimes is not passing. Any idea? Here is my code. Thanks

```
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20));
        IWebElement firstCategoryLink = wait.Until<IWebElement>(driver=> driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(table.Rows[0]["category"].ToString())));
        firstCategoryLink.Click();
        IWebElement firstSubcategoryLink = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(table.Rows[0]["subcategory"].ToString())));  
        firstSubcategoryLink.Click();
        IWebElement firstAddToCart = wait.Until<IWebElement>(driver => driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".products-list > .product > .p-link > .p-desc > .p-price-wrap > .addtocart.mid > .btn-addtocart"))[0]);
        costFirstWine = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".products-list > .product > .p-link > .p-desc > .p-price-wrap > div > .product-price"))[0].Text;
        nameFirstWine = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".products-list > .product > .p-link > .p-desc > .detail > .p-name > a"))[0].Text;
        firstAddToCart.Click();
        IWebElement secondCategoryLink = wait.Until<IWebElement>(driver => driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(table.Rows[1]["category"].ToString())));
        secondCategoryLink.Click();
        IWebElement secondSubcategoryLink = wait.Until(d => d.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText(table.Rows[1]["subcategory"].ToString())));
        secondSubcategoryLink.Click();
        IWebElement secondAddToCart = wait.Until<IWebElement>(d => d.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".products-list > .product > .p-link > .p-desc > .p-price-wrap > .addtocart.mid > .btn-addtocart"))[0]);
        costSecondWine = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".products-list > .product > .p-link > .p-desc > .p-price-wrap > div > .product-price"))[0].Text;
        nameSecondWine = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".products-list > .product > .p-link > .p-desc > .detail > .p-name > a"))[0].Text;
        secondAddToCart.Click();
```

Comment: This happens because your `WebElement` loads on the page, and then there is some javascript or something that causes the page to change. This makes the element "Stale". Once the page changes, your old element reference is no longer correct.

Comment: how can I handle this in an appropriate way? Should I use Thread.Sleep?

Comment: `Thread.Sleep` is good for debugging, but will generally make your tests flakey. You either have to make them way longer than you need so it never fails, but slows down your tests, or you make them a little too short so it passes sometimes and fails othertimes. If you add a ton of sleeps, you'll get a ton of inconsistent errors the more your tests grow. In short, try to find something to wait on that you can depend on. In this case, something other than the element you're trying to use.

Comment: You are using wait in an odd way. I would try the more common way, e.g. `wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(locator));`, etc. and see if that helps. There are many other conditions available in `ExpectedConditions` that you can try also.

Comment: I thought Selenium would not execute any code until the page had successfully loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can deal with this, I'll put them in order of my preference:

1. Find an element on your page that loads last, wait for that before doing any other action on the page. Note: this is not always possible if things aren't happening in order.

This is done easily enough with something like this:

```
By pageLoaded = By.CssSelector("#some.pageload.selector");
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(pageLoaded));
```

If you have 2 or 3 things that you know happen last, but they could happen in different orders, you could wait for all of them.

If you're using the `Page Object Pattern` you could require all `PO`'s have a `WaitForPageToLoad` method that you could work into your architecture to be called for you whenever a new `PageObject` is created. Whatever you do, trying to figure out one place to put a page load wait is important, so if the page changes you don't have to change waits in a ton of different places.

2. Have a base method that you can pass a `By` to, that will wait for an element to become stable.

I'm not going to show an example of #2, because it will slow down your tests, and there is no sure way to say how long you should be waiting for something to determine that an element is "stable". You can do this if you're desperate, but it could lead to race conditions and maintenance difficulties.

Comment: Thanks. Option 1 was great